# Reliance JIO 4G network on Manali to Leh highway

Tags: india, cellphones, road-trips, north-india, leh-india

For our upcoming road trip to Leh and other areas of Ladakh from New Delhi we would take the Manali-Leh highway and would like to know if Reliance Jio network is available on Manali-Leh route and at Leh.

Asking Reliance Jio customer support has not been of any use as they refuse to entertain any queries due to their non commercial nature of service right now and I am not a paying customer.

Please do not reply with hear say, our whole trip requires good connectivity as we would be keeping in contact with a large audience on our blog.

If mobile connectivity is not going to work with Jio then what else would work or any towns en route where there is wifi available at hotels may be? (I know BSNL and Airtel works on 2G but looking for new options since last year.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no Reliance JIO coverage anywhere in J&K. There was Reliance JIO network until Pathankot but as soon as we entered J&K it did not show up in our entire journey. Manali had Reliance JIO network throughout the town and even in near by villages. For coverage of other networks please read my reply [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73589/mobile-phone-connectivity-in-leh-kashmir).

The only network you can rely on is BSNL and that is 2G through out the Manali-Leh road.

Keylong and Jispa have some hotels where they provide high speed wifi that you can use to upload hq pictures. Lots of hotels at Leh have broadband wifi so just ask before you book your rooms.

Please note: There is no network available in most parts of Kashmir due to the security situation and curfew that is imposed so keep an eye on news.

Source : I went on a road trip to Leh in July (Srinagar-Leh-Manali).

Answer (score 2):

I am late to party and one thing that you will not receive  any kind of signal in J&K if you have prepaid sim card but if you have postpaid then you will receive only broken signals.

There's only one signal that works fine is of BSNL postpaid and realince jio is being tested in country and it has not been even at initial phase in J&K.

Rest are security measures SMS service is now working and any service may stop at any time without any proper news

Comment: I think you answer is very useful, but could you try to formulate it a bit more clearly? I am having trouble understanding what you mean. Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 0):

Listen friends, I stayed in J&K for 2 years. Firstly Jio is operational here. Works at full blast. However, it is not present at Leh. Else it is present in most of the Kashmir valley and Jammu region. However, it is also a fact that if you are entering J&K from other states then you will get roaming in postpaid sim only. Same is applicable for Jio also. I last went to Leh on an official trip in July. Until that time the only 3g network in Leh was of BSNL. However, I read somewhere that Airtel has finally deployed its 4G network in Leh. However, I can't corroborate it. For good connectivity, a working postpaid sim of BSNL or Airtel is recommended in Kashmir.